# Trying to create a repeating horizontal div scroll using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to build (or find) a rotating div example with AngularJS where I have x amount of items on an `ng-repeat`. I want to show 3 `<div>` at a time whilst having it automatically scroll horizontally 1 `<div>` at a time continuously and then repeating on a loop.

**So for example:**

I have 8 objects in an array and each object's data will fill a `<div>`. On initialisation of my page, I want to show `<div1>`, `<div2>` and `<div3>`. Then after 30 seconds, I want to show `<div2>`, `<div3>` and `<div4>` ... all the way until I get to `<div6>`, `<div7>` and `<div8>`. Then after the next 30 seconds I want to start from the beginning and show `<div7>`, `<div8>` and `<div1>`, etc.

Ultimately, I would love to add some animation to animate a scrolling/sliding effect as the `<div>` changes position, but this is not mandatory.

[image]

Comment: hi @Riples, any feedback on the answer below?

Comment: @AkberIqbal thanks for the details.  I will test your code snippet and let you know, but at a glance it does look like what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll see 4 divs at any time... the sequence will go forwards and each "next div" will replace the "first div" which is on the screen after 2 seconds... press the start button to start the loop... you can change the duration to 30 seconds in the code below also.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
/* 4 falses allowed only */
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.divVals = [{
      val: "item 0",
      effectiveIndex: 0,
      hide: true
    },
    {
      val: "item 1",
      effectiveIndex: 0,
      hide: true
    },
    {
      val: "item 2",
      effectiveIndex: 0,
      hide: true
    },
    {
      val: "item 3",
      effectiveIndex: 0,
      hide: true
    },
    {
      val: "item 4",
      effectiveIndex: 0,
      hide: true
    },
    {
      val: "item 5",
      effectiveIndex: 0,
      hide: true
    },
    {
      val: "item 6",
      effectiveIndex: 1,
      hide: false
    },
    {
      val: "item 7",
      effectiveIndex: 2,
      hide: false
    },
    {
      val: "item 8",
      effectiveIndex: 3,
      hide: false
    },
    {
      val: "item 9",
      effectiveIndex: 4,
      hide: false
    }
  ];
  $scope.checkVal = function() {
    console.log(name);
  }

  $scope.next4divs = function() {
    var counterFOUR = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.divVals.length; i++) {

      if (i == 9 && $scope.divVals[i].hide == true && $scope.divVals[0].hide == false && counterFOUR < 4) {
        $scope.divVals[0].hide = true;
        $scope.divVals[4].hide = false;
        $scope.setEffectiveIndex(1);
        break;
      } else if ($scope.divVals[i].hide == true && $scope.divVals[i + 1].hide == false && counterFOUR < 4) {
        if (i > 5) {
          counterFOUR++;
          var indexNum = i + 1;
          var turnTrue = i - 5;

          $scope.divVals[indexNum].hide = true;
          $scope.divVals[turnTrue].hide = false;
          $scope.setEffectiveIndex(indexNum + 1);
          break;
        } else {
          counterFOUR++;
          var turnFalse = i + ($scope.divVals.length - 4);
          var indexNum = i + 1;
          if (turnFalse > 10) {
            turnFalse = turnFalse - 10;
          }

          $scope.divVals[indexNum].hide = true;
          $scope.divVals[turnFalse - 1].hide = false;
          $scope.setEffectiveIndex(indexNum + 1);
          break;
        }
      }

    }
  }

  $scope.setEffectiveIndex = function(passedIndex) {
    if (passedIndex < 10) {
      $scope.divVals[passedIndex].effectiveIndex = 1;
    } else if (passedIndex >= 10) {
      $scope.divVals[passedIndex - 10].effectiveIndex = 1;
    }

    if (passedIndex + 1 < 10) {
      $scope.divVals[passedIndex + 1].effectiveIndex = 2;
    } else if (passedIndex + 1 >= 10) {
      $scope.divVals[passedIndex + 1 - 10].effectiveIndex = 2;
    }

    if (passedIndex + 2 < 10) {
      $scope.divVals[passedIndex + 2].effectiveIndex = 3;
    } else if (passedIndex + 2 >= 10) {
      $scope.divVals[passedIndex + 2 - 10].effectiveIndex = 3;
    }

    if (passedIndex + 3 < 10) {
      $scope.divVals[passedIndex + 3].effectiveIndex = 4;
    } else if (passedIndex + 3 >= 10) {
      $scope.divVals[passedIndex + 3 - 10].effectiveIndex = 4;
    }
  }

  $scope.visibilityFunction = function() {
    $interval(() => {
      $scope.next4divs()
    }, 2000);
  }


});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button type="button" ng-click="visibilityFunction('start')">Start</button>
  <hr/>
  <div class='containingDiv'>
    <div ng-repeat="item in divVals | filter: item.hide==true | orderBy: 'effectiveIndex'">
      <div class='box'>{{item.val}} <br/> {{item.effectiveIndex}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: Okay, whilst this did somewhat achieve what I was looking for, I took a different approach which allowed me to easily add animation through CSS and didn't seem so complex.